# Error Firebase Database paths must not contain only in phone

Tags: android, emulation

The error in the application summary, when trying to save an image with an id that joins the date with the day in the emulator keeps it perfectly in the database of firebase but when trying to do the same in a real device, it stops working application with the error

*com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: Feb 04, 201904: 06: 11 AM. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', Or ']'*

here is the code if necessary

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

```
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM,yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calendar.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calendar.getTime());

    productRandomKey = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;

    final StorageReference filePath = ProductImagesRef.child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + productRandomKey + ".jpg");

    final UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putFile(ImageUri);
```

I know that when the id is generated, there is a point but why in the real device the application stops and in the emulator does not?